# Jquery animate different Element

Tags: jquery, html

how to animate 2 different element in div on mouseenter and revert on mouse leave.

Icon will be center of div and when mouseover, the icon will move on left side and text will appear from left side and when mouse out, icon and text move right side, icon will be on its default position and text will disappear.

Trying to catching the div through data-type and animate them.
any reference to get best approach ?

```js
$menuItem.bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var $item = $(this),
    $wrapper = $item.children('a'),
    $movingItem = $item.find('.sti-item');

  $movingItem.each(function(i) {
    var $item = $(this),
      $item_sti_type = $item.data('type');

    if ($item_sti_type === 'icon') {
      $(this).animate({
        left: '-=20%'
      }, 100, $activ.easing, function() {
        console.log('done');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pntbx">
  <a href="#">
    <span data-type="icon" class="cctv sti-icon sti-item"></span>
    <h2 data-type="mText" class="sti-item text">Point of Sales</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide whole code.

Comment: Or a snippet or a JSFiddle